# Frequent flyer number security risk or not?

Tags: privacy, credit-card, account-security

Many booking websites or tickets "re-sellers" expose in plain view for the current authenticated user the commonly used "Frequent flyer number".

Should this be considered a security risk? Can this number be used with malicious intentions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On United States legal fields and privacy laws, PII (Personally Identifiable Information) should be protected and should not be disclosed. PII is any information used to identify a person and your frequent flyer number is unique to tag you.

In this ground, yes exposing your PII is a security concern (If this is visible in public).

Comment: by visible in public you mean: If you can see it unauthenticated or if you can see it for another user. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. If anyone can see without proper authentication/authorization will be a security violation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a security risk as you said the user is authenticated therefore only authenticated user can see "Frequent flyer number", it's up to the user if the user exposes that number. Also, I think that ticketing services have some security in place which would detect if two users try to use the same "Frequent flyer number", at least I would expect them to do some security checks.